# OSX 10.8 Server Wiki file and database location?

Tags: mac-osx, mac-osx-server, wiki

OSX 10.8.2 with the Server.app installed.

Wiki server running.

1. where do these  files live? *so that I can customize the CSS as well as back everything up.)
2. What databases so I need to backup and what is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Try looking under 
**/Library/Server** or **/Library/Server/Wiki/FileData**

(in the Finder, type Shift-command-g then paste in the above path)

This may help with the DB backup:
http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5585

This will backup the **PostgreSQL** Database to the file **/tmp/collab.pgdump**

```
sudo ./pg_dump -h "/Library/Server/PostgreSQL For Server Services/Socket" --format=c --compress=9 --blobs --username=collab --file=/tmp/collab.pgdump collab
```